# Excluding Weight Measurements that have more than 10% deviation from Starting Weight

Tags: r

So I am trying to filter out weight measurements in a df where I have weights that are outliers and I would like to see if I can condition this exclusion to leave out weight measurements that have more than 10% deviation from the starting weight.

The df looks like this currently

```
ID     Weight     Date
1      200        1/1
1      201        1/2
1      199        1/3
1      50         1/4
2      170        1/1
2      177        1/2
2      40         1/3
2      175        1/4
```

I would also want to explore the possibility of adding another condition where I want the same criteria applied with a time factor. In other words, I want to exclude any measurements that have more than 10% deviation from the starting weight over a period of time (i.e. over 10 days).

The df should look like this

```
ID     Weight     Date
1      200        1/1
1      201        1/2
1      199        1/3
2      170        1/1
2      180        1/2
2      175        1/4
```

the last row from ID 1 and the 3rd row from ID 2 where excluded.

Comment: What is the starting weight? Do you want to set a baseline weight for each ID? Or you want to calculate the mean weight across all ID, and exclude observations that deviate?

Comment: yes. I would like to establish a baseline weight for each participant then exclude any deviation that is more than 10% of that baseline weight established for each ID number.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!abs(1 - (Weight / Weight[1])) > .1) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID Weight Date 
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1    200 1/1  
2     1    201 1/2  
3     1    199 1/3  
4     2    170 1/1  
5     2    177 1/2  
6     2    175 1/4
```